# Meaning of たらたら歩く

Tags: meaning, words, usage

What is the meaning of the expression たらたら歩く?

Context: a person bumps into a child and then says 「私のせいじゃないって！たらたら歩いてるこのガキが悪いんだよ！」

たらたら means "drop by drop", but also "incessantly" or "in great quantity", so I think that used with 歩く it could mean "walking at a fast pace". Is my guess correct?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Isn't it [ガキ](http://zokugo-dict.com/06ka/gaki.htm)?

Comment: You are right, thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically たらたら is used to depict one of the three situations:

- continually dripping down
- (a talk is) long and going nowhere
- acting so dull and slow that makes one impatient

Here the third definition seems to apply. You can also say とろとろ in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

This たらたら is the same as だらだら (*sluggishly*, *slowly*, *idly*, etc.) in this context. The kid was walking slowly, not at a fast pace.

Answer (score 1):

I searched in japanese and I found a few different definitions.
Here is the closest I got.

タラタラするな : 人に速やかな行動を促す際の表現